# Is IAM Role only applicable to the resource which initiates the communication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to properly understand what is meant by IAM role. The more I read, I am getting more confused. I have also seen this link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201214/use-of-security-groups-vs-role/51203267#:~:text=Security%20groups%20are%20more%20about,firewall%20that%20controls%20the%20traffic.&text=IAM%20Roles%20are%20more%20used,actions%20and%20resources%20in%20AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201214/use-of-security-groups-vs-role/51203267#:%7E:text=Security%20groups%20are%20more%20about,firewall%20that%20controls%20the%20traffic.&text=IAM%20Roles%20are%20more%20used,actions%20and%20resources%20in%20AWS).

From what I understood:

1. Is IAM role only applicable to the resource which initiates the communication? The target of the communication can restrict using NACL, Security Groups, Subnets etc. But that is not the case I think - S3 bucket also you can attach IAM policy. So I am confused when to consider IAM role and when not.
2. What if, some external resource (not within AWS), wants to access a service within AWS (maybe a web application)? Suppose it is a public web application (no authentication). If so, will we have to consider IAM role? I know there are several ways to deploy the web application - using AWS Amplify or S3 bucket or write your own application etc.

Answer (score 2):

Please read and work through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html, IAM **is** a difficult topic and it takes a lot of practice and reading and working with it to fully understand it.

1. NACL, Security groups, subnets operate on a different level, have nothing to do with IAM, as the linked answer suggest. S3 can have a bucket policy that is "combined" with the policies your role has to compute wether an operation is allowed or not
2. If you publicly host the endpoint you *can* disable IAM, e.g. in an ApiGateway or CloudFront => S3. Internally the permission between the ApiGateway and the underlying lambda or CloudFront interacting with S3 is once again handled via IAM but that is not visible to the outside user